# On weak*-sequentially completeness

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I want to prove that every dual space is weak*-sequentially complete.

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $(f_n)$ be a weak* Cauchy sequence in $X^*$. Thus for all $x\in X$, $(f_n(x))$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb K$. Thus for all $x\in X$, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$ exists. If I define $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$ for all $x\in X$, then $f$ is linear. But how to show that it is bounded. Had $X$ been given a Banach space I could have done it by using Banach-Steinhauss theorem. But now how to proceed? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $(f_n)$ is weak* Cauchy in $X^*$? I don't think your result is true. Let $X$ be the set of real sequences of finite support with the $\ell_1$ norm. Define $f_n\in X^*$ by $f_n(x)=x_1+2x_2+\cdots+n x_n$. Then for $x\in X$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x) $ exists; so $(f_n)$ is weak* Cauchy. $(f_n)$ cannot be weak* convergent, though, since its "limit" must be $(1,2,3,\ldots)$.

Comment: Yes I meant $(f_n)$ weak*-Cauchy in $X^*$. I have corrected it now. Your example clearly shows that my assertion is false. This will be true if $X$ is a Banach space.

Answer (score 1):

Hint **:** You can use the following corollary of **Banach-Alaoglu Theorem** **:**

Let $ X $ be a normed space. Then every bounded subset of $ X^* $ is relatively weakly$^*$ compact.

Comment: It's not clear how this helps, because we would still need to show that the sequence $f_n$ is bounded.

Comment: And as David Mitra's example shows, in fact $f_n$ does not have to be bounded, and the desired statement is actually false.

Comment: @NateEldredge This result is true for Banach space $ X $ (In David Mitra's example $ X $ is not complete).